# Max array range limit

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I'm working on code for a 2D game where the player has 3 hearts.

If the player collides with a bombPrefab, he loses 1 heart. If the player collides with a heartPrefab, he wins an extra heart. If he collides 3 consecutive times with a bombPrefab, the game ends.

The Hearts texture is as follows. Array 0 (3 hearts) array 1 (2 hearts) array 2 (1 heart).

I am having a problem limiting the array! I want to know how to get the following response: If the player has 3 hearts and collides with a heartPrefab, only the object is destroyed, there is no change in the number of hearts the player has.

The code below works to take and give extra hearts. But when I collide with one heartPrefab, and I already have 3 hearts (maximum) I get the error: index is out range array.

How should I proceed? C#  answer if possible

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Heart : MonoBehaviour
{


    public Texture2D[] initialHeart;
    private int heart;
    private int manyHeart;

    void Start ()
    {

        // The game start with 3 hearts at RANGE 0
        GetComponent<GUITexture> ().texture = initialHeart [0];
        heart = initialHeart.Length;

    }


    void Update ()
    {

    }

    public bool TakeHearts ()
    {
        if (heart < 0) {

            return false;

        }

        if (manyHeart < (heart - 1)) {

            manyHeart += 1;
            GetComponent<GUITexture> ().texture = initialHeart [manyHeart];
            return true;


        } else {

            return false;

        }   
    }

    public bool AddHearts ()
    {
        if (heart <= 2) {

            return false;

        }

        if (manyHeart < (heart + 1)) {

            manyHeart -= 1;
            GetComponent<GUITexture> ().texture = initialHeart [manyHeart];
            return true;


        } else {

            return false;

        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code that initializes `initialHeart`?

Comment: @Quantic  I have created GameObject (renamed to Hearts) inside Unity, added GuiTexture and Heart Script, i can set the array by inspector =]

Comment: `if (manyHeart < (heart + 1))` should be `if (manyHeart > 0)` I think.

Comment: @GunnarB. dont work, when player colide with heartPrefab nothing happens ( no lose, no win). But ty =]

Comment: It has to be something about this because currently your code can run into negative indices which will generate the error when you try to call `initialHeart[-1]`. See answer of MatthewS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating the if statements (unless there is some other reason for doing so)... var manyHeart and heart are always inversely related. Simply use:

```
public bool AddHearts ()
{
    if (manyHeart > 0) {
        manyHeart -= 1;
        GetComponent<GUITexture> ().texture = initialHeart [manyHeart];
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much! But now, how i can destroy heartPrefab if the player have 3 hearts?

Comment: You probably have your `OnColliderEnter` function (or similar) somewhere that calls a destroy for the instantiated heart the player runs into and also calls `AddHearts`. If so that should actually work just fine since destroying that GO and adding hearts to the player are two seperate tasks. If not you will have to provide the code that actually calls `Add/TakeHearts`.

Comment: @GunnarB.yes i have: `void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D colisor)
 {

  if (colisor.gameObject.tag == "Bee") {

   Som ();

   heart= GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Heart").GetComponent<Heart> () as Heart;

   if (vida.AddHearts ())
    Destroy (gameObject);
  }


  if (colisor.gameObject.tag == "floor") {
   Destroy (gameObject, 1.5f);

  }

 }` but, if player have 3 heart heartprefab dont destroy, why?.

Comment: Because you have `if (vida.AddHearts ()) Destroy (gameObject); `. You probably just put those as two seperate calls: `vida.AddHearts(); Destroy(gameObject);`. And both `AddHearts` and `TakeHearts` don't really need to have a return type, they could just be `void`, at least for this.

Comment: Looks like you're saying:    if (vida.AddHearts()) { Destroy (gameObject)};  But if they have 3 hearts, AddHearts returns false, right? So therefore, it doesn't destroy. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: And shouldn't `vida` be `hearts`?

Comment: Sorry Gunnar, I'm always echoing you right on the tail end of your comments.

Comment: @GunnarB. yes vida = hearts i forgot to translate this part =]

Comment: @MatthewS Nah, obviously this will happen here ;)